# Google maps in Swift(iOS)calculation of duration from the json

Tags: swift, google-maps

Iam having three pickers pointing on the map.First i had found the duration between the source to waypoint and then second i found the duration between the waypoint and the destination.
Now the problem is that how to add those two durations in the days,hours,minutes format.
I parsed the values from the json through url.
Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: do you use google maps Distance Matrix API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start?

Comment: yes i used it to get the time but i need to sum up the two times from the two json's i got

Answer (score 0):

if you are using google maps Distance Matrix API, you should get below part from json

```
"duration" : {
    "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
    "value" : 13725
}
```

the value like 13725 is the number of seconds for the trip duration, so we need to put them into DateComponents object the take the values from it:

```
        var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT:0)!
        let unitFlags: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.minute, .hour, .day, .second]

        let nowDate = Date()
        let durationDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 13725)


        let components = calendar.dateComponents(unitFlags, from: nowDate,  to: durationDate)

        //Now you can get the values from components obj
        print("Comps :: ", components.day, components.hour, components.minute, components.second) calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT:0)!
        let unitFlags: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.minute, .hour, .day, .second]

        let nowDate = Date()
        let durationDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 13725)


        let components = calendar.dateComponents(unitFlags, from: nowDate,  to: durationDate)

        //Now you can get the values from components obj
        print("Comps :: ", components.day, components.hour, components.minute, components.second)
```

Comment: Thanks will try it.